# What are the possible values of the last digit of $4^m$, where m is a natural number?

Tags: number-theory

What are the possible values of the last digit of $4^m$, where m is a natural number?

After trying a couple of m=1,2,..., I found that the possible values for the last digit are 4 if m is odd and 6 if m is even. How would I prove this in general?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Case $1$.** $m$ is even, So $m=2k$ for some integer $k$.
$$4^m=2^{2m}=2^{4k}=16^k$$
But $$16^k \equiv 6^k\equiv 6 \bmod 10$$
Therefore $$4^m\equiv 6 \bmod 10$$
**Case $2$.** m is odd so $m-1$ is even. By the **case $1$** we have
$$4^m=4\cdot 4^{m-1}\equiv 4\cdot 6\equiv 4 \bmod 10 $$

Answer (score 3):

You could use mathematical induction on $m$. That is, you show that if $m = 1$, then the last digit of $4^m$ is either $4$ or $6$.  Then show that if $m$ is an integer and the last digit of $4^m$ is either $4$ or $6$, then the last digit of $4^{m+1}$ is either $4$ or $6$.

Answer (score 2):

You can prove this by taking 4 * 4 mod 10 and noting that you get 6, and taking 6 * 4 mod 10 and noting that you get 4.

Answer (score 1):

Probably the simplest for this is to prove **by induction**: 
You only have to calculate $\ (10k+4)\cdot 4\ $ and $\ (10k+6)\cdot 4$.

Answer (score 1):

The last digit of a number will correspond to the residue class to which that number belongs $\pmod{10}$.  So your question boils down to finding the numbers $x$ for which following holds when $m \in \mathbb{N}$:

$$4^m \equiv x \pmod{10}$$